# Is there a decorator equivalent to PyXll `@xl_func(macro=True)` with xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

Is there a decorator equivalent to PyXll `@xl_func(macro=True)` with xlwings?

This would allow to interact with the entire workbook in Excel?

A dummy example: `=test()` in cell 'E5' returns an error:

```
@xw.func
def test():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range('A1').formula = wb.name
    return 'done'
```

> Unexpected Python Error: TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be
>   sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.

For the sake of clarification: I would like to be able to write Excel functions, without arrays formulas or buttons or macros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `xw.sub`, from the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#macros):

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.sub
def my_macro():
    """Writes the name of the Workbook into Range("A1") of Sheet 1"""
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = wb.name
```

Comment: I think this is a macro, not an Excel function anymore. Meaning I cannot use it from an Excel workbook unless I add a button which is not what I need to do. If I run "=my_macro()" in Excel, it returns the error "the name that you entered is not valid"

Comment: Can you point me to the docs in pyxll of what you want to do?

Comment: Sure: [link](https://enthought.pyxll.com/api/decorators.html#xl-func) (have a look at the `macro` argument. It allows the function to be registered as a macro sheet equivalent function (vs. a UDF). An example is provided here: [link](https://enthought.pyxll.com/examples/automation.html)

Comment: Please look at the `def automation_example(rows, cols, value)` in perticular

Comment: Ah I see, you're interested in the async call really. That's not supported yet, but if you want to achieve something like in this example (write outside of the cell) then yes, this is a feature we're working on currently.

Comment: Great, looking forward to giving it a try :)

Comment: I used a work around with `multiprocessing.pool.apply_async` from a UDF. It triggers other issues but I managed to get something working well in the end.